# Dynamic column generation in Postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I need help to generate dynamic columns but in following format:

1 Rows * (4 Fixed columns)  - 4 columns repeated for one first id value 
Ex : If 8 ids in first column the 8 * 4 columns will be created 
I have made it successfully in SQL Sever 2008 but now I want to do it in Postgres.

For that I have following data :

```
CREATE TABLE T (cdfid int , headcategoriesid nvarchar(4) , headid int , grade int);
INSERT INTO T
    (cdfid  , headcategoriesid  , headid  , grade )
VALUES
(69,    7,  301 ,3001)  ,
(69,    8,  301 ,3002), 
(69,    6,  302 ,3001), 
(69,    5,  302 ,3001), 
(69,    4,  303 ,3002), 
(69,    3,  303 ,3001), 
(69,    15, 304 ,3001), 
(69,    9,  304 ,3002), 
(69,    1,  305 ,3001), 
(69,    2,  305 ,3003);
```

My Output as showin in image 
[image]

I want this output in Postgres

Query of SQL Server

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(headcategoriesid + Col)
                                FROM    T
                                        CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('_headid'), ('_grade')) c (col)
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


select @Cols 





  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) ='select * from 
(
    SELECT  [Col] = headcategoriesid + ''_'' + col,
                                                    Value,headcategoriesid
                                            FROM    T
                                                    UNPIVOT
                                                    (   Value
                                                        FOR Col IN ([headid], [grade])
                                                    ) Upvt 
            ) p
            pivot (
            Sum(Value) for [Col] in ('+@Cols+') ) as oc'
```

Comment: Please show us the query that you use for SQL Server. Posting results as images is usually frowned upon. It's better to add them as (formatted) text.

Comment: pls check edited block

Comment: Do you need values other than the ones on the diagonal? PostgreSQL has a limit of 250-1600 columns in a table, which might be relevant in this case. (Not sure about query results, though.)

Comment: But its a query .. nt storing any where... 1600 column limit ? r u sure ?

Comment: @tsnorri : I dun have problem with column numbers , but required to generate it as show in image.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the id numbers so that the number of columns won't get too big? If all the values except the ones on the diagonal will be NULL, the query could be changed so that the diagonal will be returned.